# What's the correct way to cite a generic website (not wikipedia) with biblatex package and bibtex syntax?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, formatting, citing

I have searched on this community and around the net but have always found different versions, the syntaxes that seem most suitable to me are:

```
@online{knuthwebsite,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url  = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
}
```

or:

```
@misc{knuthwebsite,
  author = "Donald Knuth",
  title = "{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
  year = "2022",
  howpublished = {\url{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html},
  note = "[Online; accessed 15-September-2022]"
 }
```

What is the difference between them,are there alternatives to be used?

Comment: If you are using `biblatex`, the first version is almost good, but `addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",` should be `urldate = {2016-09-01},`. The second entry is missing a closing curly brace in `title = "{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}",`, though it is debatable whether curly braces should be used here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the style used.

The first assumes the style implements an `@online` type and has built  support for a `url` field. This for example is not true of the core bibtex styles such as `plain` (which predate the web)

The second just assumes a `@misc` type which is almost always defined, and a definition of a `\url` macro, which is usually supplied by `url` or `hyperref` packages.

So the second is perhaps more general but as the url is just in a plain text field marked up in TeX it gives less metadata to the bibliography system to style or search on URL for example, so which is best just depends...